# How many arcseconds the light of a star unfolds in the vicinity of jupiter?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, planets, jupiter

One of the main demonstrations made to test the theory of relativity were the images of the solar eclipse of May 26, 1919, (causing a shift in the positions observed in celestial coordinates of its source stars 1.7 arcsec, the amount predicted by theory). If the same experiment was carried out, but with a star on the periphery of the edge of jupiter, the same effect would occur? Few arcseconds that star would unfold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct simple formula that gives a VERY close approximation (in the 'weak field' approximation) is **[4G/c^2][M/R]**
... where M is the mass of the object, and R is the radius of closest approach of the light. Note that since the first term is a constant, the deflection varies as M/R.

See here for an incorrect and correct derivation: 
http://home.fnal.gov/~syphers/Education/Notes/lightbend.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For the sun, the deflection of starlight is $1.75''/b$, where $b$ is the apparent distance from the sun's center in solar radii.  I'm going to make an educated guess that the 1.75 arcseconds is proportional to $GM_\text{sun}$.  Jupiter has something like 1/1000th the sun's mass, so the deflection of starlight for an object occulted by Jupiter would be milli-arcseconds.  That starlight can get perhaps ten times closer to Jupiter's center than to the sun's center without getting absorbed doesn't increase the deflection very much.

Comment: Your educated guess is correct :)

Comment: @jormansandoval [You're welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).